# Typescript define generic constructor function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use Typescript with a JS library that has psuedo-classes, with `extend()` functions that provide inheritance. I'm stuck on how to pass different constructor functions to new "classes":

```
type A = (param1: string, param2: number);
type B = (param3: number, param4: number);

interface BaseClass {
    extend<Constructor>(): {
        new(); // How would I associate this function with type Constructor?
    }
}

var NewClass = BaseClass.extend<A>();
new NewClass('Hello world', 3); // type checked against type A

var SecondClass= BaseClass.extend<B>();
new SecondClass(4, 5); // type checked against type B
```

I've tried this:

```
interface BaseClass {
    extend<Constructor>(): {
        new(): Constructor;
    }
}
```

But that expects `new NewClass()` to *return* type A.

I've tried this:

```
interface BaseClass {
    extend<Constructor>(): {
        new<Constructor>();
    }
}
```

But that doesn't type check `new NewClass()`.

What is the correct syntax for associating a function with a type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a workaround for the `new()` constructor. I changed the types to include the `new` keyword themselves:

```
type A = {
    new(param1: string, param2: number);
}

type B = {
    new(param3: number, param4: number);
}
```

Then I can return the constructor from the `extend()` call like this:

```
interface BaseClass {
    extend<Constructor>(): Constructor;
}
```